# Traverse folder to convert all contained files

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I've recently started using ffmpeg with the intention of converting my video library to h265 due to its compression benefits. I would like to run one command and have ffmpeg traverse the folder converting each file, one-by-one into h265. I've checked the documentation [Here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) but I can't get my head around it. Does anybody have a template loop script for me to use?

I have ffmpeg installed on a Linux box and have successfully converted single files but I have around 400 files to convert, hence the looping question.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
The files I'm waiting to convert are videos with varying containers. I have bee using the python script below, which I have tweaked to suit my needs but isn't working. I will include the error I'm getting and a link to the original below my code.

```
import os
import sys
import re
import shutil
import subprocess


__author__ = 'Nikhil'

# Edit options here ##################################################
outmode = 'mp4'                          #Extension of file
remover = True                           # Delete original file after conversion complete
accept_ext = 'mp4 mkv avi divx m4v mpeg mpg wmv'   #Extensions of video files to convert

ffmpeg_exe = "ffmpeg"                    #Path to ffmpeg executable
ffprobe_exe = "ffprobe"                  #Path to ffprobe executable
mkvextract_exe = "mkvextract"            #Path to mkvextract executable
video_codec = 'libx265'                  #Video codec to use
video_type = 'h265'                      #Name of video codec to check for remux
audio_codec = 'aac'                      #Audio codec to use
audio_type = 'aac'                       #Name of audio codec to check for remux
crf = "28"                               #Video quality for libx264
vbr = ''                                 #Audio quality
extract_subtitle = True                  #Extract subtitles?
subtitle_languages = "en eng english"    #Codes for languages to extract
threads = 0                              #Number of threads to use in ffmpeg, 0 defaults to all
additional_ffmpeg = '-preset slow -movflags +faststart'     #Additional flags for ffmpeg, preset sets speed and compression, movflags to make file web optimized

## END OPTIONS - DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING ##

outformat = 'mp4'
if outmode == 'mp4':
outformat = 'mp4'
elif outmode == 'mkv':
outformat = 'matroska'


def ffmpeg(*args, **kwargs):
largs = [ffmpeg_exe, ]
largs.extend(args)
try:
return subprocess.check_output(largs, **kwargs).decode('utf-8')
except:
return None

def getoutput(cmd):
if sys.version < '3':
try:
return subprocess.check_output(cmd.split(' '))
except:
return None
else:
return subprocess.getoutput(cmd)

formats = ""
if getoutput(ffmpeg_exe + ' -formats'):
formats = getoutput(ffmpeg_exe + ' -formats 2')
else:
exit(1)

if ('E mp4' in formats) and ('E matroska' in formats):
print("You have the suitable formats")
else:
print("You do not have both the mkv and mp4 formats...Exiting!")
exit(1)

codecs = getoutput(ffmpeg_exe + ' -codecs 2')

if video_codec in codecs:
print("Check " + video_codec + " Audio Encoder ... OK")
else:
print("Check " + video_codec + " Audio Encoder ... NOK")
exit(1)

if audio_codec in codecs:
print("Check " + audio_codec + " Audio Encoder ... OK")
else:
print("Check " + audio_codec + " Audio Encoder ... NOK")
exit(1)

print("Your FFMpeg is OK\nEntering File Processing\n")

subtitle_languages = subtitle_languages.lower()

def process_file(path, file):
extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1].replace(".", "")
filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]

if extension in accept_ext:
print(file + " is an acceptable extension. Checking file...")
else:
print(file + " is not an acceptable extension. Skipping...")
return

if ffprobe_exe:
file_info = getoutput('"' + ffprobe_exe + '"' + " " + '"' + os.path.join(path, file) + '"')
else:
file_info = ffmpeg("-i", os.path.join(path, file))

if 'Invalid data found' in file_info:
print("File " + file + " is NOT A VIDEO FILE cannot be converted!")
return

encode_crf = []
if file_info.find("Video: " + video_type) != -1:
vcodec = 'copy'
print("Video is " + video_type + ", remuxing....")
else:
vcodec = video_codec
if crf:
encode_crf = ["-crf", "" + crf]
print("Video is not " + video_type + ", converting...")

encode_vbr = []
if "Audio: " + audio_type in file_info:
acodec = 'copy'
print("Audio is " + audio_type + ", remuxing....")
else:
acodec = audio_codec
if vbr:
encode_vbr = ["-vbr", "" + vbr]
print("Audio is not " + audio_type + ", converting...")

if extension == outmode and vcodec == 'copy' and acodec == 'copy':
print(file + " is already " + outmode + " and no conversion needed. Skipping...")
return

print(
"Using video codec: " + vcodec + " audio codec: " + acodec + " and Container format " + outformat + " for\nFile: " + file + "\nStarting Conversion...\n")

filename = filename.replace("XVID", video_type)
filename = filename.replace("xvid", video_type)

try:
args = ['-i', os.path.join(path, file), '-y', '-f', outformat, '-acodec', acodec]
if encode_vbr:
args.extend(encode_vbr)
args.extend(['-vcodec', vcodec])
if encode_crf:
args.extend(encode_crf)
if additional_ffmpeg:
args.extend(additional_ffmpeg.split(" "))
if threads:
args.extend(['-threads', str(threads)])
args.append(os.path.join(path, filename + '.temp'))
ffmpeg(*args)
print("")
except Exception as e:
print("Error: %s" % e)
print("Removing temp file and skipping file")
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, filename + '.temp')):
os.remove(os.path.join(path, filename + '.temp'))
return

if extract_subtitle and (file_info.find("Subtitle:") != -1):
print("Extracting Subtitles")
matches = re.finditer("Stream #(\d+):(\d+)\((\w+)\): Subtitle: (.*)", file_info)
for m in matches:
if m.group(3).lower() not in subtitle_languages.split(" "):
continue
try:
if 'subrip' in m.group(4):
sub_format = 'copy'
sub_ext = '.srt'
elif mkvextract_exe and 'hdmv_pgs' in m.group(4):
subprocess.check_output([mkvextract_exe, 'tracks', os.path.join(path, file),
m.group(2) + ':' + os.path.join(path, filename + '.' + m.group(
3) + '.' + m.group(2) + '.sup')])
continue
else:
sub_format = 'srt'
sub_ext = '.srt'
ffmpeg("-i", os.path.join(path, file), '-y', '-map', m.group(1) + ':' + m.group(2), '-c:s:0',
sub_format,
os.path.join(path, filename + '.' + m.group(3) + '.' + m.group(2) + sub_ext))
print("")
except Exception as e:
print("Error: %s" % e)
print("Deleting subtitle.")
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, filename + '.' + m.group(3) + '.' + m.group(2) + sub_ext)):
os.remove(os.path.join(path, filename + '.' + m.group(3) + '.' + m.group(2) + sub_ext))

if remover:
print("Deleting original file: " + file)
os.remove(os.path.join(path, file))

if outmode == extension:
shutil.move(os.path.join(path, filename + ".temp"), os.path.join(path, filename + ".enc." + outmode))
filename += ".enc"
else:
shutil.move(os.path.join(path, filename + ".temp"), os.path.join(path, filename + "." + outmode))


def process_directory(path):
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, ".noconvert")):
return
for file in os.listdir(path):
filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
if os.path.isdir(filepath):
process_directory(filepath)
elif os.path.isfile(filepath):
process_file(path, file)


for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
if os.path.isdir(arg):
process_directory(arg)
elif os.path.isfile(arg):
process_file(os.path.dirname(arg), os.path.basename(arg))
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/media/569f/ethan1878/bin/convert.py", line 209, in <module>
process_file(os.path.dirname(arg), os.path.basename(arg))
File "/media/569f/ethan1878/bin/convert.py", line 100, in process_file
if 'Invalid data found' in file_info:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

and the original file is hosted [Here](https://us.v-cdn.net/6025034/uploads/editor/7y/hfu6x9oxt5gm.txt) (as a .txt file)

Comment: The keyword you need is 'recursive'. Explore the threads in http://stackexchange.com/search?q=ffmpeg+recursive

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have files of varying extensions. How would I go about doing this? I'm currently editing a Python script I found online but keep getting errors.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have also edited my question to prevent duplication.

Comment: You didn't mention python previously. I re-opened the question. I don't know anything about python.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I didn't know I'd be using Python until after I posted this question - apologies for not editing beforehand. I have tried your solution and it does work... BUT I need it to be able to traverse directories. E.g: tell it to watch /media/Video and it traverses /media/Video/2014 then /media/Video/2015 etc